How to expand a volume group from a single physical volume
I am using LVMs on RHEL9. I have a logical volume on a partition(/dev/sda4) and need to give it more space. I went into VMWare and made the drive larger. I then expanded the partition using parted and ran "resizepart 4 100%". Then I ran "pvresize /dev/sda4". This grew the physical volume. Now I need to grow the volume group but I am not sure how to do that. When I run "vgdisplay", it shows the extra space is there but not allocated (See below). Can someone please help?
Alloc PE / Size       6862 / 26.80 GiB
Free  PE / Size       56420 / 220.39 GiB

The volume group is one or more physical volumes, it's simply a way of grouping physical volumes together into one group, hence the name. The VG now contains the expanded PV, and is the same size as that PV, so you should already have the space in your volume group. You simply need to expand your logical volume, and then your file system.

You need to expand the logical volume. E.g.:
lvextend --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/vg-lv1

